# How to popup a file dialog/print dialog in a html file that is rendered in a WebEngineView?

Tags: qt, highcharts, qml, qtquick2, qwebengineview

I have a local html file that use highcharts to display my data and save to images, it works well in chrome browser, then I try to load it in Qt 5.9.4 with a WebEngineView (QML type),  all the popup dialogs are unable to dispaly.

html file code: https://jsfiddle.net/sylaince/9x9j5Lpj/

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; min-height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        navigation: {
            menuItemStyle: {
                padding: '6px 14px'
            }
        }
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        exporting: {
            filename: 'data'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'export file'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'test data',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
</script>
```

qml file:

```
Page {  
    WebEngineView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "qrc:/html/index.html"
    }
}
```

How to make WebEngineView to show dialog such as file dialog, print dialog, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop ups are of 3 types:

1. Print preview
2. Download files.
3. Navigating to another page

So indicate the solution in parts:

#### 1.Print preview

It appears it's still not implemented in Qt: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57982, an workaround suggested in the comments of tickets is to print in PDF and then to show that PDF (for example, with pdf.js), I have tried it but I have not had luck.

#### 2.Download files

This question is similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164712/how-to-open-download-file-dialog-with-qwebengineview-on-pyqt5) that I answered.

As I said in my previous answer: *That popup window is generated by the browser, in the case of `QWebEngine` we must create it*.

to create the dialog we can use the QML `FileDialog`, but these are not blocking so you will have to accept the download and that behavior is not what is seen in a conventional browser, so my solution will use the QWidgets `QFileDialog` since Allows waiting and being able to verify acceptance. For the implementation implement a helper that allows us to manage it.

```
class DownloadHelper: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void onDownloadRequested(QObject * download){
        QString old_path = download->property("path").toString();
        QString suffix = QFileInfo(old_path).suffix();
        QString path  = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, "Save File", old_path, "*."+suffix);
        if(!path.isEmpty()){
            download->setProperty("path", path);
            bool accepted = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(download, "accept"); 
            Q_ASSERT(accepted);
        }
    }
};
# ...
DownloadHelper helper;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("downloadHelper", &helper);
# ...
```

***.qml**

```
WebEngineView {
    id: webView
    anchors.fill: parent
    url: "qrc:/html/index.html"
    profile.onDownloadRequested: downloadHelper.onDownloadRequested(download)
    // ...
```

#### 3.Navigating to another page

When the *"Open in HighCharts Cloud"* menu is pressed, it launches a request to open a new window, to use it we use the `newViewRequested` signal creating a window dynamically:

```
WebEngineView {
    id: webView
    // ...

    onNewViewRequested: {
        var newWindow = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick.Window 2.2;
                                            import QtWebEngine 1.5;
                                             Window {
                                                width: 640; height: 480;
                                                visible: true;
                                                property alias wv: wv
                                                WebEngineView{id:wv; anchors.fill: parent}}',
                                           webView,
                                           "dynamicSnippet1");
        console.log(newWindow.wv)
        request.openIn(newWindow.wv)
    }
```

<sub>The full implementation can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50180990).</sub>

Comment: it's awesome! Thanks very much!

Comment: There is another problem. It works in debug mode, dialog can open properly but  no file downloaded in release mode. Have you found this problem?

Comment: Q_ASSERT，that's the problem

Comment: full implementation link is not correct could you share it?

Comment: second method is not working `Cannot call method 'onDownloadRequested' of null`!

Comment: @MahdiKhalili Are you sure? Have you executed the project that is in the link at the end of my answer?

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah it runs , but it's not working maybe because i'm using different version of qt ' 5.13.1 ' , i am talking about second method not third one

Comment: @MahdiKhalili mmmm, My project implements all the parts, they are not different solutions but different parts of the same solution.

Comment: @MahdiKhalili I just tested my project with Qt 5.13.1 on Linux and it works correctly.

Comment: @eyllanesc it was building problem , i should've cleaned then built the project , its working now.

Comment: For the second answer, I got an error message while linking: `Unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl DownloadHelper::metaObject(void)  const`. Could you help me to solve it?